# Different classes (all extending the same class) in a list/array (java)

Tags: java, arrays, list, class, superclass

I want to make a list of instances of classes. The instances belong to different classes, though they all belong to the same super class. Is this something I should avoid? Or is this fine. Any suggestions on how to best implement this, would be great.

For example, I have a super class Vehicle and two other classes, Bike and Car as classes that extend Vehicle. For convenience I want to store all Vehicles in one array/list as I want to display all vehicles using a simple loop.

Hope I am not seriously overlooking something and this doesn't turn out to be too trivial (or just bad practice).

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you show some code? You could simply use an `ArrayList` that holds `Vehicle` instances.

Comment: Yes, you can do this, but remember that when retrieving entries from the list, you can only assume that you're getting a `Vehicle` back and you can only call methods declared on `Vehicle` without `instanceof` checks and class-casting. The correct solution depends on what you're doing with the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It surely is a *legal move*:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Vehicle> list=new ArrayList<>();

        list.add(new Car());
        list.add(new Bike());
    }
}

class Vehicle{}
class Car extends Vehicle{}
class Bike extends Vehicle{}
```

but it all depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: The fact that you state that it is a legal move, kind of suggests it is bad practice... is that the case?

Comment: Absolutely not. I meant to say that I cannot tell you if it's a bad practice, because it actually depends on the context. Legal construct, good practice, if not misused =)

Comment: What I try to do is make a new app for managing tasks. In my approach I want to use different types of tasks. In the app, I want to be able to list all tasks, but alternatively also specific types of tasks, depending on what the user is looking for at a given point in time.

Comment: Well, it seems to be a reasonable solution. Polymorphism in action!